# Applying CGAffineTransform to CGPath

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

What I am trying to do is to apply a CGAffineTransform to a CGPath.

I know, if I were drawing onto a CGContext, I would just transform the context itself.

But what I want to do is to apply a transform to the actual path itself. UIBezierPath allows me do to this with the applyTransform: method, it doesn't transform it's CGPath.

Is there any way to apply a CGAffineTransform to a CGPath itself??

Comment: "it doesn't transform it's CGPath"? When I apply the transform to a `UIBezierPath`, its backing `CGPath` _is_ transformed, so I can get the _transformed_ `CGPath` with `bezierPath.CGPath` property.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath` which creates a copy of your path, transformed by a given `CGAffineTransform`. There's also `CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath` for creating a mutable copy.

Note that both of these functions have been introduced in iOS 5.

If you need something that works on earlier versions of iOS, you could create an empty path (`CGPathCreateMutable`) and add your other path with `CGPathAddPath` which optionally takes a transformation as its second parameter.